# Serializing Objects in AS3, String type too small to hold blob

Tags: string, actionscript-3, serialization

I'm using:

```
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import mx.utils.Base64Encoder;
    import mx.utils.Base64Decoder;
    .
    .
    .
    public static function serializeToString(value:Object):String{
        if(value==null){
            throw new Error("null isn't a legal serialization candidate");
        }
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bytes.writeObject(value);
        bytes.position = 0;
        var be:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
        be.encode(bytes.readUTFBytes(bytes.length));
        return be.drain();
    }

    public static function deSerializeFromString(value:String):Object{
        var dec:Base64Decoder=new Base64Decoder();
        dec.decode(value);
        var result:ByteArray=dec.drain();
        result.position=0;
        return result.readObject();
    }
```

But I keep getting an "Error #2030: End of file was encountered."

This is (probably) because the class I'm serializing is too big for the "String" object type in AS3.

Is there a limitless object for storing an array of characters (or better yet binary), or am I going to have to make my own class? (like one with an array of strings)

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with the `String` class? I don't think that `String` actually has a hard limit - it should only be limited by memory. Here's a test - try filling a string with random characters for 100000 iterations (or something bigger than your class size) and see if/when it breaks. You can use a simple `for` loop with a random base64 character every time. If it works, then the `String` isn't your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have no other explanation, this should be a simple serialization...

Comment: http://blog.flexmaniak.pl/wrrors-and-warnings/flex-errors/error-2030-end-of-file-was-encountered

Comment: You are already using ByteArray.. Try to comment out all Base64Decoder parts from your code.

Comment: Fixed like so:
    public static function deSerializeFromString(value:String):Object{          

        var dec:Base64Decoder=new Base64Decoder();          
        dec.decode(value);          
        var result:ByteArray= dec.toByteArray();
        result.position=0;          
        return result.readObject();         
    }

Comment: You should write up your solution as an answer instead of a comment.  Make sure to accept it also.  Otherwise it will make it hard for others to easily see what the solution was in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another efficient, cross-platform way of serializing objects is by using JSON.
Here is a library for as3:
https://github.com/mherkender/actionjson